# CompletitionService: poll timeout without reset it every time?

Tags: java, executorservice, completion-service

I have a set of task which must be completed within a certain time, interrupt them otherwise. In particular uploads the same file on different Servers through `FTPClient` class.

I thought that the `CompletionService` was the best solution for my problem, but the only problem is that the timeout used in `poll` is renewed at every element returned by the callable task, am I right? Sorry if I'm not, it's the first time that I use this mechanism.

Anyway, this is not what I'm looking for because I want to set an upper bound for the completion of **all** the submitted task, not an upper bound for the next task completed!

There is any solution/workaround for this problem?

Comment: [ExecutorService#invokeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)  does exactly that.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing, thanks so much! However, there is something that is not totally clear: suppose that the size of the callables collection is 50. Let's suppose now that only 10 successfully ends their task before the timeout: the returned List has size 50, but how can I tell which of them are completed or not?

Comment: Maybe the answer is simply "test it with `isCancelled()` before call `get()`", since each  task which  was not completed is cancelled?

Comment: That's correct.  `isCancelled()` is the way to go.  Don't rely on `isDone()` because it will always return true;

Comment: I noticed it in the documentation, thanks for the confiirmation anyway! :) PS: if you'll post your solution as a normal answer I'll choose it